# Why does rank correlation only depend on copula, and not on the margins, if the margins are continuous

Tags: correlation, continuous-data, ranking, copula, kendall-tau

I read that for continuous margins, then Rank correlation only depend on copula and not on the margins.  However, it is not the case for the non-continuous margins.  Is that because the Kendall's tau (for example) has a tie if the margins in not continuous? And why it then does not only depend on copula?

Any idea?